# Need Help: Finding some solutions manual for Multivariable Mathematics

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm a college sophomore student majoring in mathematics. In the first semester，someone highly recommend me to read this book:
 *Multivariable Mathematics: Linear Algebra, Multivariable Calculus, and Manifolds* by Theodore Shifrin. Until now，I have already finished the previous chapters studying by myself. I need to check my answers to this book's exercies and to improve the quality of my proof. If this book is accompanied by a solutions manual, so much the better.

Indeed, from this book’s Preface, I know there is an instructor solutions manual (ISBN 0-471-64915-5) for the book, but I have no access  to buy\ free download  it . Would you please give me some information about this manual, so that I can buy it or download it for free? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Ted Shifrin himself is on this site so you might be able to talk to him in chat.

Comment: @TedShifrin Hello!

Comment: This textbook is still in print in the publisher's (Wiley) catalog.  That tends to be a guarantee that solutions-manuals (for the current edition, at least) will _not_ be "on the market" (and some publishers _actively_ check to make sure no one is making copies available on the 'Net).

Answer (score 1):

Note that instructor manuals are supposed to be available only to instructors, and not to students :) That's why, in general, it's not (too) easy to obtain one unless you can prove to whomever is selling them that you are, indeed, an instructor.

Comment: If I were an instructor，I would think there must no need to find the solutions manual.Whatever,I will try my best to deal with these exercises.thanks

Comment: Note that I did not say that every instructor gets a solution manual. 
I said that *only* an instructor gets a solution manual.
That's because the instructor generally does not need the solutions, but needs to keep the solutions *away from the students*, so that the students can be assigned the exercises in the book as homework :)

Comment: Oh, I see now . Thanks for your revise .